# filter items based on multiple properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter, frontend

I am trying to **filter** an array of objects based on both **title** and **description**.
It is working fine for a single item, how can I filter items based on both title and description.
Here is my code.

```
import * as React from "react"

const items = [
  {
    title: "React",
    description:
      "React (also known as React.js or ReactJS) is a JavaScript library for building user interfaces. It is maintained by Facebook and a community of individual developers and companies."
  },
];


export default function App () {
  const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = React.useState("");
  const inputRef = React.useRef();
  
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    inputRef.current.focus();
  }, []);
  
  const handleChange = event => {
    setSearchTerm(event.target.value);
  };
  
  
  const filteredNames = items
    .filter((entry) =>
      entry.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
    )
 
  return (
    <>
      <header>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Type to filter..."
          value={searchTerm}
          onChange={handleChange}
          ref={inputRef}
        />
      </header>
      <ul>
        {filteredNames.map(({title, description}, i) => (
          <li key={i} className="box">
            <h1>{title}</h1>
            <p>{description}</p>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </>
  )
}
```

I tried with filtered chaining

```
  const filteredNames = items
    .filter((entry) =>
      entry.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
    ).filter((entry) =>
      entry.description.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
    )
```

However, this not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filter function expects a boolean query, and will run through the iterable list, and return every item that will return true for that boolean query.

```
const filteredNames = items.filter(item => {
  return item.title.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) ||
  item.description.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase())
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is the same as using an AND conditional. The first filter returns only title matches and the second returns title matches that also have description matches. You want OR instead

You can use Array#some() as an OR conditional

```
const filteredNames = items.filter(({title,description}) =>
   const term = searchTerm.toLowerCase();
   return [title, description].some(str => str.toLowerCase().includes(term));
})
```